# I need to replace door insulation on self cleaning oven, but cannot locate the type of insulation

Tags: insulation, doors, oven

The door insulation was unusable after a spill, what insulation can I use?

Canadian Model GE GRCR3820ZWW-2, 1999.  Cannot locate a part number and my local suppliers say discontinued with no replacement.

Comment: Replacement parts are readily available for nearly any oven made in the last half century. You might add some information to your post about yours. This isn't something you fabricate.

Comment: I am not sure what your model is in the USA, but a GE door gasket kit is available, that works on Kenmore, Hotpoint and GE models, ranging in price from $15 to over $200.

Comment: You would need to search on a parts website to find the exact replacement part, or measure the old one, or the door, to determine a generic replacement size.